# Sample code or tutorial for drawing square in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, quartz-graphics

Hi i need some help for drawing square in sample iphone app.So if someone can provide me tutorial or source code it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of information in the [Drawing and Printing on iOS Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH1-SW1)

And if you want Sample Code - there is the [Quartz Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531) application

Answer (score 1):

You can use this really helpful link:  http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

Worked for me, also, if youre wondering how to change colors, assign floats to the RGBSetColorStroke and then change them with IBActions, the color codes are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And also, if you wanna change the thickness with a uislider, just make a float, say, float = [slider value]; Then assign that float to the Thickness line: CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

OK!

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[paintingImage.image drawInRect:self.view.frame];
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor    whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200));
paintingImage.image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Video on making rainbow glow draw app:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGxf1Lity3k